# How to match recharts dots to legend type

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Hoping there is a way outside of creating a custom dot react element to have the line chart dots match the legend type. IE if my code looks like this:

```
  <Line
          legendType='square'
        />
```

I want a square dot and respectively for triangle, etc.
So far the only solution I have found is to follow this example: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedDotLineChart with svgs matching the recharts elements but am hoping for something cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Recharts (I'm on v2) does not currently support using squares for dot shape, so you need to create your own custom shape. Here's what I did for squares and triangle dot shapes.

```js
// CustomDot.tsx
import React from 'react';

export function renderCustomDot(
    cx: number, 
    cy: number, 
    key: string, 
    color: string, 
    shape: 'triangle' | 'square', 
    value: number, 
    length = 8
): JSX.Element {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) return <span key={`${key}-${Math.random()}`} />;
  switch(shape) {
    case 'triangle':
      return <ChartDotTriangle key={`${key}-${Math.random()}`} cx={cx} cy={cy} fill={color} length={length} />;
    case 'square':
      return <ChartDotSquare key={`${key}-${Math.random()}`} cx={cx} cy={cy} fill={color} length={length} />;
    default:
      return <span key={`${key}-${Math.random()}`} />;
  }
}

export type ChartDotInput = {
    cx: number;
    cy: number;
    fill?: string;
    length?: number;
}

/** *
 * Move point to the new coordinate regarding center
 *
 * @param point The coordinate of point
 * @param center The new center
 * @param centerOld The old center
*/
function movePointToNewCoordinates(
    point: [number, number],
    center: [number, number],
    centerOld: [number, number]
  ): [number, number] {
    const x = point[0];
    const y = point[1];
    const xCenter = center[0];
    const yCenter = center[1];
    const xCenterOld = centerOld[0];
    const yCenterOld = centerOld[1];
    return [x - xCenter + xCenterOld, y - yCenter + yCenterOld];
}
  
/** *
 * Rotate point
 *
 * @param point The coordinate of point
 * @param center The angle in radians
*/
function rotatePoint(point: [number, number], angle: number): [number, number] {
    const x = point[0];
    const y = point[1];
  
    const xNew = x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle);
    const yNew = x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle);
  
    return [xNew, yNew];
}

/** *
 * Calc points of the triangle
 *
 * @param cx The X-coordinate of the center of triangle
 * @param cy The Y-coordinate of the center of triangle
 * @param sideLength The length of the side
 * @param angle The angle in degrees
 */
function calcTrianglePoints(cx: number, cy: number, sideLength: number, angle = 0): string {
    const r = (Math.sqrt(3) / 3) * sideLength; // The radius of the circumscribed circle
    const h = (Math.sqrt(3) / 2) * sideLength; // The height of median
  
    const angleInRadian = (Math.PI * angle) / 180;
  
    const pointCenter: [number, number] = [cx, cy];
    const pointCenterNew: [number, number] = rotatePoint(pointCenter, angleInRadian);
  
    // 1st point
    const point1 = movePointToNewCoordinates(
      rotatePoint([cx, cy - r], angleInRadian),
      pointCenterNew,
      pointCenter
    );
    const x1 = point1[0];
    const y1 = point1[1];
  
    // 2nd point
    const point2 = movePointToNewCoordinates(
      rotatePoint([cx - sideLength / 2, cy + (h - r)], angleInRadian),
      pointCenterNew,
      pointCenter
    );
    const x2 = point2[0];
    const y2 = point2[1];
  
    // 3rd point
    const point3 = movePointToNewCoordinates(
      rotatePoint([cx + sideLength / 2, cy + (h - r)], angleInRadian),
      pointCenterNew,
      pointCenter
    );
    const x3 = point3[0];
    const y3 = point3[1];
  
    return `${x1},${y1},${x2},${y2},${x3},${y3}`;
}

/** *
 * Calc points of the square
 *
 * @param cx The X-coordinate of the center of square
 * @param cy The Y-coordinate of the center of square
 * @param sideLength The length of the side
 */
function calcSquarePoints(cx: number, cy: number, sideLength: number): string {
  const xLeft = cx - (sideLength / 2);
  const xRight = cx + (sideLength / 2);
  const yTop = cy + (sideLength / 2);
  const yBottom = cy - (sideLength / 2);

  const [x1, y1] = [xLeft, yTop];
  const [x2, y2] = [xRight, yTop];
  const [x3, y3] = [xRight, yBottom];
  const [x4, y4] = [xLeft, yBottom];

  return `${x1},${y1},${x2},${y2},${x3},${y3},${x4},${y4}`;
}

export function ChartDotTriangle({
    cx,
    cy,
    fill,
    length,
}: ChartDotInput): JSX.Element {
    length = length || 6;
    const angle = 0;
    return (
      <polygon width={length} height={length} cx={cx} cy={cy} fill={fill} points={calcTrianglePoints(cx, cy, length, angle)} />
    );
}

export function ChartDotSquare({
  cx,
  cy,
  fill,
  length,
}: ChartDotInput): JSX.Element {
  length = length || 4;
  return (
    <polygon width={length} height={length} cx={cx} cy={cy} fill={fill} points={calcSquarePoints(cx, cy, length)} />
  ); 
}
```

```js
// MyChart.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { ComposedChart, Line } from 'recharts';

  <ComposedChart>
    ...
    <Line
      type="monotone"
      dataKey={'myDataKey'}
      legendType={'square'}
      isAnimationActive={false}
      dot={(dotProps: { cx: number; cy: number; key: string; value: number; }) =>
            renderCustomDot(dotProps.cx, dotProps.cy, dotProps.key, 'black', 'square', dotProps.value)
        }
    />
  </ComposedChart>;
```